# Display and hide div in django using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am having a problem with implementing display and hide `div` function using Javascript for a Django form.
I have a dropdown selection in one form, I used the following code to iterate over the choices:

```
<select class="my_choice">
    {% for x,y in form.select_option.field.choices %}
        <option value="{{ x }}"{% if form.select_option.field.value == x %} selected{% endif %}>{{ y }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Now after selecting an option form the dropdown menu I have to press the submit button in which the form is navigated to another form. Here I want to show appropriate `div`s based on the selection from the previous form.

So here's the deal:

1. I have to choose an option from the dropdown menu
2. Based on the drop down menu option from the previous form some forms
   should be show in the next form and rest should be hide.

Comment: have you completed the Django tutorial? do you know how Django forms and views work? what have you tried?

Comment: Why hide the nonrelvant forms via JS when you can not include them in the markup? Some `if` logic in your templates should do the trick.

Comment: If you are not refreshing the page and want to use jquery, then simply doing $("#mydif").show(); and $("#mydiv").hide(); should work.  If you want to initialise fields as hidden, put style="display:none;" in the html otherwise they appear until your jquery runs and hides them.